# How to explore the SQLite db while the app is running? Eclipse (Juno) > Android (adb)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, debugging

I have an application, which is behaving weird at the moment. It's using an SQLite database, and it worked pretty well before I wanted to improve some parts of it. Now comes the problem: How could I "explore" my database while the application is running on my phone?

Like you can watch variables, and check them if you break the debug session at some point.
But with the SQLite database. (The application of course got a "Main" status where it's idle, where I could check the database.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
adb shell
sqlite3 /data/data/com.app.name/databases/DatabaseName.db
```

which will take you to the SQLite command line. From there, you can perform SQLite queries/data dumps on your database to see the data inside. If you want to do this with a real device (i.e. not the emulator), then you will need to root your device first.

---

### Note:

If your device doesn't let you execute the `sqlite3` binary (or the binary doesn't exist in the device's path... or it just doesn't exist all together, etc.), you can install `sqlite3` on your local machine and then do

```
adb pull /data/data/com.app.name/databases/DatabaseName.db .
sqlite3 DatabaseName.db
```

which will copy the database to your local directory and then execute the `sqlite3` binary on your local machine. This happened to me once when I rooted my Motorola Xoom... but the first suggestion works fine on most devices (at least in my experience).

Comment: The simple shell -> sqlite returns a permission denied error, but this is the right track. The second would be great, but I would need root rights to pull the file. How do I do that?

Comment: Okay I used the shell and su to copy the file into the sdcard. Then I pulled it from there. One additional step, but got the job done. Awesome!